# begin selection with second row of data

Tags: mysql, select, row

I need to begin my selection starting with the second row of data.  This  query works fine

```
SELECT   Sum(ttimediff) as 'TOTAL IDLE TIME (sec)' FROM temp where ttimediff>@3;
```

I just need it start with the second row, and read all rows after that.

I have tried `FROM temp ORDER BY asc LIMIT 2 where ttimediff>@3;` but I believe the limit statement is stopping the selection at 2.  I get a syntax error

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` is missing the expression to use for ordering.  Without ordering there is no row numbering.  What are you actually trying to achieve? What is special about the **first** row?

Comment: The numbers in the timediff field are a unix date stamp.  The first number in the row, is necessary to calculate time spans, however when I am looking for a sum of instances where the seconds exceeded a threshold, it skews my results.  Having the selection and the summation begin with the second row and count forward, at first, seemed like the easiest option

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Limit but you need to have 2 Arguments like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1, 5000
```

This will skip 1 element and check until 5000

Comment: I have tried SELECT  Sum(ttimediff) as 'TOTAL IDLE TIME (sec)'
FROM temp Limit 1, 5000 where ttimediff>@3; and I get a syntax error

Comment: @damond: `FROM`->`WHERE`->`LIMIT`. BUT without `ORDER BY` it's meaningless.